# Python: How to group statements like how JavaScript is able to with parenthesis

Tags: javascript, python

Can I group statements into a single expression similar to how I can in Javascript? In JavaScript, I can do things like this with parenthesis:

```
let value = (a && a.constructor === Array || false);
let expression = (
(a.constructor === Number && a > 5) && (b.constructor === Number && b > 5)
) || null;
```

Can things like that be done in Python?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be asking "Is it possible in python to construct an assignment statement that assigns one value if a conditional passes, and assign a different value if it fails?", in which case you might try `value = a if a.b == c else d` or perhaps `value = a and a.b == c or d`. Hard to say whether either of these behaves identically to their JS counterparts, since I'm not well-versed in that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does have much to offer in this realm: e.g. you can combine boolean operations like this `(a && (b || c))` in js and can do `(a and (b or c))` in python. You can do ternary operations `a ? b : c` (if `a` is true, evaluate to `b` else to `c`) in js and `b if a else c` in python (same). You can do `a && b` in js (if `a` evaluates to true, the expression evaluates to `b`) and `a and b` in python. Similarly for `a || b` in js and `a or b` in python. Although they might not behave exactly the same since they are two different languages but largely corresponds.

Answer (score 1):

Python does have this functionality. For example, if you have an if statement, you could write something like the following:

```
age = 30
if (age != 0 and age >= 16):
    print("You can drive!")
else:
    print("You can't drive. Maybe later.")
# This example ends up printing out "You can drive!"
# Instead of using && and ||, you normally use `and` as well as `or`
```

Parentheses work the same in Python.